# Choosing files in flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask

Currently I am using flask for backend and javascript(& HTML) for front end . I am reading a file from form field in HTML and , sending it to backend (flask) and reading the file to from end as followsas follows :

```
<input  id="upload_input" name="file" type="file"/> {frontend : HTML form}

f = request.files['file']  {backend}
```

I am using file chooser to choose a file .
After processing the file I am sending output to front end . Now Having done this I come back to front end . Again after displaying the information recieved from backend , I want to use the same file  (that is I want to resend the same file back to backend) .But I want some mechanism in which I donot have to choose my file again (because it is the same file I chose earlier ), anyhow my application understand to re-read the same file . Can someone please help me on that ?

Comment: Maybe explain a bit more what the second call to the server does with that file. Couldn't you just execute what it does directly from the first call?

Comment: You could try using sessions, and store the file for the session. Look at https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/ for some code examples. For example, you can save a `filepath` key in the session.

Comment: Does the following express your main question: "How can my application remember a filepath?"

Comment: @this-vidor : Yes that is actually what I mean .

Comment: @Shef : Your Idea is working fine for me :D Thanks alot !

Comment: @danish I've un-deleted my "answer", which is really just a tip. But this must mean that your "file chooser" is not simply the input element itself; that element has a `FileList` of `File` blobs, which know about a file and its name, but not its filesystem path.

Comment: @danish Glad to help! I've posted my answer, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at Flask Sessions. Link here: [Flask-Session](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session)

This will allow you to store the file in a directory on the server (using regular python file I/O) then access its path as `session['filepath']`. Make sure to delete the file once the session is done to free up space.

Answer (score 0):

The path to your local file is just a string. Since you state in your question that you do want to "resend the same file back to backend", it is really the client (browser) that should do the remembering.

1. If your page doesn't reload between requests, you can just store it in a variable! But I'm sure this has occurred to you.
2. You can store the string using the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` APIs. These are very easy to learn. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) are some documentation.